# How do I map a table field to a variable of different name in a doctrine entity?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a variable $pk in my model/entity class. I want to map it to the table_pk field in my table.

How do I do this?

I'm reading this manual => http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column. but nothing seems to do what I want.

an example on how this can be done using annotation and yaml mapping would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is quite simple (the `@ORM\GeneratedValue` bit is needed only if your PK is auto incremental):

```php
namespace MyNamespace;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_entity")
 */
class MyEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(name="table_pk", type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

And the same entity mapped with YAML configuration

```yaml
# MyNamespace.MyEntity.dcm.yml
MyNamespace\MyEntity:
  type: entity
    table: my_entity
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      column: table_pk
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
```

And as a bonus, XML mappings:

```xml
<!-- MyNamespace.MyEntity.dcm.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping 
    xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
    http://raw.github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/master/doctrine-mapping.xsd"
>
    <entity name="MyNamespace\MyEntity" table="table_name">
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="table_pk">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```